# Magneto2.3.1 How to customize checkbox with compare link display on product detail page

Tags: magento2, compare, checkbox, product-detail-page

I am using Magneto2.3.1 and i need to customize the default magento compare link on detail page. I want to show checkbox with compare label and if i checked than product compare successfully and if unchecked than not compare.

I shared here screenshots please lookout it:

[image]

Comment: try with observer

Comment: Use jQuery . Put submit event on checkbox click

Comment: onclick try with $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_compare_add_product', ['product' => $product]); this event..

Comment: please describe it and full code

Comment: Like onChange="this.form.submit()"

Comment: please describe it more